# Illustrator artwork present but not showing on layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm editing an existing AI file - a hexagon shape that shows with some scratches over it. However, I've removed every single object on the current layer except the hexagon shape.

I can't figure out where the scratch effect is coming from. There are no styles applied to the layer or object, there are no masks.

- Layer:
- ->Shape:

When I move the shape around, the scratch marks do not move, and if moved to a new layer added below this one, the scratches don't appear. They're somehow tied to that layer...

I need to be able to move this effect with the shape.

[image]

Comment: Is it an Opacity Mask? (Seen in the Transparency Panel)

Comment: Doesn't appear to be. That panel says "click to create a mask" for both the layer/object.